# Php - Secure way to give access of a file via Downloading to the End User?

Tags: php, security, websecurity

This is more of a security question that i am not sure if this approach is safe and secure enough way to download a file and present to a web user ?

We have customers invoice files stored in a server location (publicly inaccessible location), then we do read them via the PHP code in a file (in public location with a file ) like below,

of course we authenticate the user with the session before accessing them, however if the end-user knows where the files are he can manipulate his request to read UN-authorised invoices.

I just wonder, if this way of

**1. Presenting files to the end-user is secure enough ?**

**2. End user will not have any knowledge at all, of where the files are stored in the server ?**

**3. Any other recommendation on how to handle similar situation ?**

```
$i = $invoice->get();
$filename = sprintf(INV_PDF_FILENAME,$i['customerid'],date('Ymd',$i['dateIssued']));
$x = sprintf('/tmp/invoices/%s',$filename);
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Pragma: cache');
header('Cache-Control: private');
readfile($x);
```

Comment: where does `$invoice` come from, do they have any control over this is the question. For example if you use an order id to create the invoice and that id is part of the url then someone could feed it any order id (in theory). Without knowing how the invoice object is created who can say, as all the info comes from that...  Something like `$filename = sprintf(INV_PDF_FILENAME,$current_user_id,date('Ymd',$i['dateIssued']));` would be better.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I understand what you are saying, There is no way user can manipulate the invoice object as we validate it against the user session. My questions is more of a Will the enduser will ever know the location of the files from outside

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, assuming there are no other vulnerabilities (i.e. the user being able to alter the parameters that go into `$filename` to perform directory traversal attacks).
2. Barring any additional vulnerabilities, the code provided will not leak its local file path to the end user.
3. [Make sure uploaded files are stored outside the document root](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/10/how-securely-allow-users-upload-files). Verify that `realpath($x)` begins with the directory you expect them to be located in.

For example:

```
$x = sprintf('/tmp/invoices/%s',$filename);
$realpath = realpath($x);
if (strpos($realpath, '/tmp/invoices/') !== 0) {
    // Note: The strict comparison to 0 matters.
    // It means that the real file path must begin with "/tmp/invoices/"
    // or else this redirect/exit gets called.
    header("Location: /error");
    exit;
}
```